# How to make smooth edge of box with materials?

Tags: modeling, materials

I have the following box:

[image: picture of box]

What I would like to achieve is to have a smooth edge in the top-right corner, so it looks like a curve.

What I've tried is to make the faces really small, and then apply my red texture to just a few of them, but it still looks hacky.

[image]

Anyone sitting on any nice techniques for achiving something like this:

[image]

Notice how the black color is kind of rounded around the corner

Comment: how about at texture?

Comment: @David yeah, this answer suggests that as well: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/103240/53858 I'm wondering what that "masking" part is called so I can still decide the material without having to edit and reimport a texture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do this with textures?

Simply make a black-and-white image texture, and use it to switch between two different material node layouts. It'll be better for performance as well, because there's fewer faces.

Comment: Oh, that sounds good to me! I'll give that a try. What is the "use it to switch between two different material node layouts" part called so I know what to search for? Feels similar to what "masking" would do, is that the right term?

Comment: Yes, this is masking. You use a Mix Shader node to mask between completely different material trees, or a MixRGB node if all you want to change is the color. Or you can just plug your image texture straight into the shader node if you want a color image.